# JPA relation between Orders and Employee

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, jpa

I am creating an order and later assigning an employee to that order. So I am having trouble in making relation between these two. My order table doesnot update the employee_id column

**My Employee class**

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "servedBy")
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
private List<Orders> orders;
...
}
```

**My Order class**

```
@Entity
public class Orders {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Embedded
private OrderStatus orderStatus;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
private Employee servedBy;
...
}
```

**Code Where I am trying to map these two**

```
public void orderServed(Long employeeId, Long orderId)  {
    Orders order = orderRepository.findOne(orderId);
    Employee employee = employeeRepository.findOne(employeeId);
    List<Orders> orders = employee.getOrders();
    orders.add(order);
    employee.setOrders(orders);
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you change `SAVE_UPDATE` to `ALL`?

Comment: What are the codes that save `Employee` and `Orders` ?

Comment: @Andronicus I did changed to ALL, but nothing happened.

Comment: Two things: are you sure, the order that you want to add is not already in? Are you overriding `equals` & `hashCode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "servedBy")
    private List<Orders> orders;

}
```

`mappedBy` here means `servedBy` in `Orders` are used to maintain the relationship between `Employee` and `Order` ,which means Hibernate will update the foreign key based on this field. You have to set the value of `servedBy` in `Order` to specify the relationship rather than using `orders` in `Employee` :

```
public void orderServed(Long employeeId, Long orderId)  {
    Orders order = orderRepository.findOne(orderId);
    Employee employee = employeeRepository.findOne(employeeId);

    //Set the forign key
    order.setServedBy(employee);

    employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
```

BTW , `@OneToMany` already allow to configure the cascade behaviour. No need to use hibernate 's `@Cascade` :

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "servedBy" , cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Orders> orders;

}
```